# Empty div to get spacing according to design using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

For bannerimage section which has texts on the specific position, I don't want to write custom CSS to place the div. The below code fits correctly according to design and it's good in responsive also. I've not used this code everywhere but only in 1 section where there is a condition to display div or text at a specific position. I don't want to write custom CSS. But using bootstrap empty div problem is solving, Is this correct or not.

```
<div class="mainbannerimagewithtext">
<div class=" row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 py-5 ">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
<div class=" row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 py-5 ">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
<div class=" row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 py-5  ">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
<div class=" row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 py-5 ">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
<div class=" row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 py-5 media ">
    <div class="col px-5 ">
        <p class="twentyfive ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <p class="fifteen">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class=" ">
        <div class="text-start px-5 py-5">
            <p class="adm-nf-twenty"></p>
            <p class="adm-nf-twentyitalic"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class=" ">
        <div class="text-start px-5 py-5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class=" ">
        <div class="text-start px-5 py-5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class=" ">
        <div class="text-start px-5 py-5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class="bluebox ">
        <div class="text-start px-5 py-5">
            <p class="twenty">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <p class="twentyitalic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <p class="fifteenwhite">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <p class="fifteenwhite">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <p class="fifteenwhite"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is you should consider using [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/#offsetting-columns) for the best practice, also you can customize it for all available screen size Bootstrap provided.

**Like this for example :**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">normal .col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-4 getting offset for 4 col in md screen size</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 getting offset for 3 col in md screen size</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 getting offset for 3 col in md screen size</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 getting offset for 3 col in md screen size</div>
      </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Also always remember offset always arrange the column to the right**